# Visual Studio 2017 generates TypeScript errors for a project that does not use TypeScript

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-2017

Any ideas about why VS2017 would run the TypeScript compiler (tsc.exe) on a project that does not use TypeScript would be helpful?

I have a solution that contains three ASP.Net Web Applications.  One of the three uses TypeScript while the other two projects contain no files with a .ts extension, no tsconfig files, and no Typesctript MSBuild tags.  However, one of the two projects that do not use TS generates the following TypeScript compiler errors when the project is built, and even when the solution is first opened.  I removed the project name from the listed errors below, but I assure you that these errors are attributed to one of the projects that do not use Typescript.

This issue does not exist when I open (or build) the same solution in Visual Studio 2015.

Error   TS2451  Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'JSON'.   (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TypeScript\lib.es6.d.ts   991 Active
Error   TS2451  Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'JSON'.  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TypeScript\lib.es6.d.ts   991 Active
Error   TS2451  Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'JSON'.  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TypeScript\lib.es6.d.ts   1018    Active
Error   TS2451  Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'JSON'.  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TypeScript\lib.es6.d.ts   1018    Active
Error   TS2451  Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'JSON'.  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TypeScript\lib.es6.d.ts   5714    Active
Error   TS2451  Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'JSON'.  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TypeScript\lib.es6.d.ts   5714    Active
Error   TS2403  Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'require' must be of type 'any', but here has type 'NodeRequire'.   C:\Users\gregb\AppData\Local\Microsoft\TypeScript\node_modules\@types\node\index.d.ts   73  Active
Error   TS2403  Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'require' must be of type 'any', but here has type 'NodeRequire'.   C:\Users\gregb\AppData\Local\Microsoft\TypeScript\node_modules\@types\node\index.d.ts   73  Active
Error   TS2403  Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'swfobject' must be of type '{ registerObject: (ab: any, X: any, aa: any, Z: any) => void; getObjectById: (X: any) => Element;...', but here has type 'SwfObject'.  C:\Users\gregb\AppData\Local\Microsoft\TypeScript\node_modules\@types\swfobject\index.d.ts  6   Active
Error   TS2403  Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'swfobject' must be of type '{ registerObject: (ab: any, X: any, aa: any, Z: any) => void; getObjectById: (X: any) => Element;...', but here has type 'SwfObject'.  C:\Users\gregb\AppData\Local\Microsoft\TypeScript\node_modules\@types\swfobject\index.d.ts  6   Active

Comment: A fix is coming according to this: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14565

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49128453/how-can-i-suppress-spurious-typescript-compilation-errors-in-vs2017