# How can I suppress spurious Typescript compilation errors in VS2017?

Tags: typescript, msbuild, visual-studio-2017

We have a .Net project with some embedded resources that are xml files with a custom filename extension.

For some reason, on my computer, Visual Studio has suddenly (for the last few days) decided to treat these as TypeScript files and is producing tens of thousands of compile errors on each build.

[image]

The errors don't stop the build, but they do slow it down and make it hard to work out what the real errors are when I have them.

So far I've tried adding

```
<TypeScriptCompileBlocked>true</TypeScriptCompileBlocked>
```

to my csproj files, and I've looked at the "Compile on Save" setting for Javascript and it is not enabled. Neither of these fixes seem to work.

We don't have any TypeScript in our project at all.

I'm running Visual Studio 2017 15.5.7

Nobody else in my team is reporting this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some experimenting, I discovered how to suppress these messages in my circumstances.

At some point, I had registered a file extension as a type of file to be edited in VS with the XML editor. This is done via:
Tools, Options, Text Editor, File Extension

I had added my file extension as an extension that should be edited with the XML editor like below:
[image: Settings for file extension association]

After I removed the association, the compile errors stopped appearing.

I don't know what caused Visual Studio 2017 to decide that files to be opened in the XML editor should be treated as TypeScript files and compiled. However, the reason I added the extension no longer applies, so I happily removed it.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to get rid of the TS errors hence the build failures with below settings in VS 2019

Tools > Options > Text Editor > JavaScript/TypeScript > Code Validation > JavaScript Errors > Set the values under *JavaScript Errors* to False.

[image]

Comment: It would be even better to write this as text too, just in case the image hosting may expire one day!

Comment: @XouDo, thanks for the comment and the post is now updated.

Comment: This answer helped me to build my project. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

> How can I suppress spurious Typescript compilation errors in VS2017?

If you can make sure those build errors are Typescript compilation errors, you can try to following methods to suppress Typescript compilation errors:

Add TypeScript transpilation blocked in your project file .csproj(What you have done):

```
<PropertyGroup>
     <TypeScriptCompileBlocked>true</TypeScriptCompileBlocked>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Make sure you are including your typescript files as content:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="**\*.ts" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Add a tsconfig.json file to your project root and make sure `compileOnSave` is set to false:

```
"compileOnSave": false,
```

If all above not help you and you don't have any TypeScript to compiled in our project, you can go to Tools -> Extensions & Updates, and **disable Typescript Build for Microsoft Visual Studio**.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I don't have any typescript files in my project though. I am getting these errors because Visual Studio has decided that some of our included resources are actually typescript files and they aren't.

Comment: Also, I looked at Tools, Extensions and Updates, and there is no Typescript Build listed there. The extension is not installed.